# Jersey How to specify dependence between 2 services?

Tags: jersey, wadl, orchestration

I have 2 services accessible on my server, and i want to specify that on service depends on the other, so that it is executed only when the other one was successfully executed. 
Is there a way (may be an annotation) to specify it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You saying the second service shouldn't be accessible unless the first has been succeeded? Sounds like this could/should be done in code with a simple flag. If the flag isn't set and the second service is called, return an error.